# How to test the length of a new line when using u_fgets in ICU4C ustdio.h?

Tags: c++, c, readfile, icu4c

In ICU4C,

```
UChar * u_fgets(UChar *s, int32_t n, UFILE *f)
```

will read one line from `f` into buffer `s`, which size is `n`.

But how can I know this one line's length ?

What will happen if `n` is not enough for this one line ?

Comment: Hopefully the same as the usual `fgets()` - the last character will be a newline if a complete line was read, and the last character actually read if there wasn't enough space for a full line. But check the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I know this one line's length ?

**If** `u_fgets()` works similarly to the standard `fgets()` it will put a '\0' after the last character read. Then you can get the length by calling `strlen()` or its equivalent version for your system.

> What will happen if n is not enough for this one line ?

**If** `u_fgets()` works similarly to the standard `fgets()` it will stop filling characters into the buffer `s` so that '\0' gets into the last cell. This will be the `n`th character at `s[n - 1]`. Characters not stored will remain in the input stream `f`.

---

However, please read the documentation! That is always your first stop.